# OpenVPN works on Windows, fails on Linux VPS

Tags: openvpn

I need to configure a OpenVPN connection which is working successfully on Windows, but after trying it on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on DigitalOcean it fails with the following output:

```
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=273565 Current Parameter Settings:
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=273892   config = 'VPN.ovpn'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=274158   mode = 0
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=274423   persist_config = DISABLED
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=274670   persist_mode = 1
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=274847   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275017   show_digests = DISABLED
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275178   show_engines = DISABLED
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275352   genkey = DISABLED
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275513   key_pass_file = '/etc/openvpn/psk.pass'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275688 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=275855 267 variation(s) on previous 10 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=276058 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan  9 2019
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=276260 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=276483 WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/auth.txt' is group or others accessible
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=280348 WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/cert_export_Cliente.key' is group or others accessible
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=280690 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1559 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=280905 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=281991 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1559 D:1450 EF:59 EB:12 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=282182 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=282375 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=282573 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'dfa3fe29'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=282748 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '3e5d5b9b'
Tue Oct  1 13:33:13 2019 us=282929 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy [nonblock]
Tue Oct  1 13:33:14 2019 us=283319 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy
Tue Oct  1 13:33:14 2019 us=283727 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Tue Oct  1 13:33:14 2019 us=283966 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy
Tue Oct  1 13:33:14 2019 us=284370 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy, sid=0b902ea0 7f60a7fd
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=680440 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=XXXXXX
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=681045 Validating certificate key usage
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=681337 ++ Certificate has key usage  00b6, expects 00a0
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=681559 ++ Certificate has key usage  00b6, expects 0088
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=681796 VERIFY KU ERROR
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=682061 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=682256 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=682469 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=682702 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=682894 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=683149 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Tue Oct  1 13:33:15 2019 us=683327 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
^CTue Oct  1 13:33:17 2019 us=514911 SIGINT[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

VPN provider says VPN is configured for Windows not for Linux but I don't trully believe this is correct. Is there a way to connect to the VPN?

This is my .ovpn file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote vpn.xxxxxxxx.com.yyy
port YYYY
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
askpass /etc/openvpn/psk.pass
ca /etc/openvpn/cert_export_SERVER.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/cert_export_CLIENT.crt
key /etc/openvpn/cert_export_CLIENTE.key
verb 4
mute 10
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
auth-nocache
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 192.168.15.254
```

Answer (score 0):

upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and connection works now.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade OpenVPN version 2.3 to 2.4 on Debian/Ubuntu
You can slove this issue by follow these steps i have tried into ubuntu 16 .you can try with ubuntu 18 or upper versions.

step 1. open the terminal with sudo user

step 2. Check the current version using the command:

```
# openvpn --version
```

step 3. Import the public GPG key that is used to sign the packages:

```
# wget -O - https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg|apt-key add -
```

step 4. Create a new source list to find the updated OpenVPN packages:

```
# echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/<version> <osrelease> main" \
  > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
```

Eg: `# echo "deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list`

step 5. Run an update.

```
# apt-get update
```

step 6. The upgrade the OpenVPN package:

```
# apt-get --only-upgrade install openvpn
```

step 7. check version

```
#openvpn --v
```

Comment: after finish the installation try to connect to vpn server using your own vpn file  #sudo openvpn --config /home/user/example.ovpn